# scrollIntoView does not include border

Tags: javascript

I'm using Javascript (no jQuery) and I have a sub-menu element that pops up which at times goes beyond the bottom of the viewer, so I used scrollIntoView to have the sub-menu instantly move to be have all the line items fully within the viewport (i.e bottom of sub-menu aligns with bottom of viewport.

```
document.getElementById('sub1').scrollIntoView(false);
```

However, I then added a 2px border to that sub-menu element, and although the line items of the sub-menu appear fully within the viewer, the border does not; it remains off the bottom of the viewport.
Is there a way to include the border in the scrollIntoView without adding another element to the page?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well.. According to CSS box model ([official W3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-box-3/#the-css-box-model)) the border is, in-fact, outside the region of the element itself (just like margin, unlike padding)

So.. I guess all you have to do is to get the value of the `top-border` of your element (dynamically) and adjust the calculation of the page scroll (already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096863/how-to-get-and-set-the-current-web-page-scroll-position)) and a little adjustment found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681002/get-border-width-from-a-div-with-plain-javascript)

```
var element = document.getElementById('sub1');
element.scrollIntoView(false);
document.documentElement.scrollTop -= element.style.borderTopWidth.slice(0, -2);
```

Comment: many thanks!  I initially tried using a ScrollBy with an arbitrary value, in addition to the scrollIntoView, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Well here is a fiddle I wrote https://jsfiddle.net/3n168sp5/.. looks fine to me. Maybe it's a view-port issue? can you reproduce this on `jsfiddle` (with view-port) or any other sandbox?

Comment: Hi ymz.  I think wasn't clear in my comment/appreciation.  I was saying that your suggestion worked! I was just saying that before your solution, I had tried that other method which for some reason did not work.  It's all good and I've marked your answer as the solution.  Thanks again.